# Is Selenium IDE useful for XHTML CSS coder?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Is [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) useful for XHTML CSS coder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate tests for your application in a simple way. Lets say you want to verify that your Form tells you that an input field is missing. Or you want to verfiy that on all browsers the H1 is present.

Or you want to test if the ajax request against an google service returns values.. and and..

You can record the tests with a FireFox Plugin, wich makes it realy easy. Further you can use an Selenium RC server, wich fires up all configured browsers and runs the tests automaticly.

[Selenium FireFox Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2079)
[Selenium RC Server](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)

Comment: Can we use this for css and xhtml w3c validation ,spell and case ceck. can we we make our custom test for any purpose and reuse on every sites ?

Comment: Hi , think about selenium as some kind of "macro" recoder. You can record to fill out an form or to press buttons. It makes no sense to check for w3c or spelling errors with selenium. You cant reuse the testcases because it records the test by names of html element ..